# I want to have particles gather instead of die on contact

Tags: animation, particles, physics

I am creating a blood flow animation where the artery is pinched off, restricting blood flow.

Right now I have a plane with a collision modifier keyframed to open and close with the artery. I also have my blood cells set to "die on hit". What I would like instead is to have the blood cells gather at the close as they would in real life.

I am looking to achieve something like this... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2vZtPXV7A0

This is what I currently have... https://youtu.be/WUs7CeagwQ4?si=B9VYz8rrjqehm2m6

Here is a link to the current version of the project if you want to take a look and play around with it yourselves... https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1t9i26EjnW4BESOVCGsJUl9dmScI89PEF?usp=sharing

Really appreciate any tips or guidance as to how to go about this!

Thanks guys!

Comment: The animation looks great. But why did you make the blood cell particles "die on hit" if you actually want them to gather at the blocked spot?

Comment: @Blunder Hey dude! Thanks for responding. I was just testing it out to see if the animation would look decent with them dying on hit, but I think the quality would be a lot higher if I had them gather. The problem is that I don’t know how to go about doing that. So as of right now I just have them dying.